# MYSQL trigger to update table field with currenttimestamp

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in mysql database. Database engine used innoDB.

- person (id, name, time_record_created, time_record_updated)
- person_status (id, person, status_msg , time_created)
- status_msg (id, status_msg)

1 to many relationship defined for person and person_status.
1 to many relationship defined for status_msg and person_status.

I am recording a person's status change history in person_status table. Statuses could be Pending, Verified, Active, Suspended. Everytime a status is changed, new entry is created in person_status table with the current timestamp.

In MYSQL, is it possible to create a trigger that everytime a new entry is made in person_status table for person X, will also update time_record_updated with current timestamp in person table for person X ?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, then this is what you are looking for:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test AFTER INSERT ON person_status
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE person SET time_record_updated=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = NEW.person;
END
```